# Is there a way to debug in WSL and simultanously non WSL application in the same instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Simple question where I cannot find an answer. I am developing in WSL where I have my backend. Due to performance issues and memory leak of serving a JS app in WSL I decided to develop frontend directly on Windows. I dont want to have two instances of VSCode, one for debugging backend (ubuntu lamp server) and one for frontend (webpack and typescript), my question is, is there a way to have both WSL and NON WSL in one instance, have separate terminals and run debug sessions ? Or not possible at all.

Comment: probably. and it would probably involve writing one of the launch configs less prettily. but I don't know exactly how- especially not without more detail about what debug support extensions you're using.